# Настройка Windows 7 при отсутствиии драйверов на usb и сеть

Tags: windows, драйвер, asus

Есть ноутбук Asus X501A https://www.asus.com/ru/Notebooks/X501A/HelpDesk_Download/

При покупке была установлена *Windows 8*. Решил поставить *Windows 7*. Поставил, но диспетчер устройств пишет, что нет драйверов под юсб. Поэтому не могу поставить драйвера на сеть.

Пытался подключится с телефона по *bluetooth*, но не получилось.

Comment: диска с дровами нету?

Comment: @Александр в  Asus X501A нет CD/DVD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Грузишься с livecd linux (например с [этого](http://torrent.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/trusty/release/desktop/xubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)), качаешь [Driver Pack Solution](http://drp.su/ru/) на бук, грузишься в винду, ставишь драйвера и на сеть и на чипсет и на всё остальное.

Answer (score 1):

Раз смогли установить Win 7 - значит, загрузка с USB работает.

Возьмите загрузочную флешку Win 7, с которой ставили (или создайте новую через USB Download Tool). Скачайте драйвера с оффсайта, закиньте их прямо на флешку.

Загрузитесь с флешки, выберите Install now/Repair your computer. Там уйдите в консоль, и скопируйте драйвера на основной диск.